# Windows authentication in azure web role

Tags: windows-authentication, azure

Is it possible to do authentication based on domain "Integrated Windows Authentication" in an Azure web role?

That is, it should authenticate the user from an on-premises domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Azure Active Directory service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/active-directory/) (also see [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/identity/what-is-windows-azure-active-directory/) for details) can do this. The price is "Free" for up to 500,000 objects. Azure AD Service will store a cache of your local AD in the Azure cloud, and if it doesn't have a certain object that it needs, it will query your AD server.

I don't think there's a way to get Azure cloud services to directly connect to and query your local AD server without using Azure AD Service, unless you run a Virtual Machine in Azure and connect it to your local network using a VPN. But that particular technique is not specific to Azure, as it would work with any externally hosted VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: After we joined the azure web role (cloud service) to the virtual network.                                                                             Is it possible to add the azure role hosted machine to on premises domain?                                                                       (that is changing the domain of azure cloud service hosted machine to on premises domain after created the site to site vpn for connecting to local<->azure machines)                                                     Please answer for this......